# GridDB No sql client will not build rpm

Tags: griddb

When I download file `griddb_nosql-4.3-rc.zip` on Github, I change the name and compress from "griddb_nosql-4.3-rc.zip" to "griddb_c_client-4.3.0.tar.gz".

After I follow guid on github. Input the following command:
`rpmbuild --define="_topdir`pwd`" -bb --clean SPECS/griddb.spec`, and I see the following notification:

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.04uTG9
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/thanhvtt/hihihi/c_client/installer/BUILD
+ cd /home/thanhvtt/hihihi/c_client/installer/BUILD
+ rm -rf c_client
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/thanhvtt/hihihi/c_client/installer/SOURCES/griddb_c_client-4.3.0.tar.gz
+ /usr/bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd c_client
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.04uTG9: line 35: cd: c_client: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.04uTG9 (%prep)
```

RPM build errors:
   `Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.04uTG9 (%prep)` .Any idea?